# Can I give subject line as 'I would be on leave'?

Tags: grammar

I am planing for a leave tomorrow (because I have some personal work need to be done); I want to send a mail to my boss, here can I choose subject line as `I would be on leave`. or is there any issue with `I would be on leave` (alternatives are most welcome). Please shed some light on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: We need rather more information about the circumstances to be able to advise you. The question could even be off-topic, as it sounds a little like proof-reading.

Comment: You would be on leave _if what happened_?

Comment: I plan to take leave/be absent tomorrow. No you cannot use "would" since it needs a cause why you might be on leave as Janus mentions

Comment: I suppose an answer might be possible explaining that *would* used in this way (expressing desire, = would like to) is **now** obsolete.

Comment: _I would be on leave if you'd let me..._

Comment: "I'm on leave tomorrow" or "Please note, tomorrow I will be on leave" or " I will be having leave tomorrow" I think your question is better suited to our English Language Learners' site [ELL](http://ell.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Subject lines are like headlines - short. Why not just *Leave* and explain in the text?

Comment: I would +1 @Skippy’s comment if I weren't so fond of the subjunctive mood. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

If your desire is to request leave time from your boss, the subject line and request should be phrased "I would like to be on leave tomorrow", or more politely, "I would like to request leave time tomorrow".

If your wish to state to him that you will not be showing up tomorrow, you should say "I **will** be on leave".

However, given that this is a subject line for an email, it can say anything you want.

For the greatest clarity, I would suggest "Leave Time On (Date of Leave)", where "(Date of Leave)" is the day you will be gone.  This will allow him to look at the email at a later date and know the day on which you were gone.  Though it might be a bit redundant if your email server already places a date mark next to the email entry.